# "npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded" when trying to install with -g

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, installation

if i use:

```
npm install -g ******
```

the terminal gives me this error:

```
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nze\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-09T11_21_27_816Z-debug-0.log
```

The mentioned log-file says this:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   '-g',
0 verbose cli   'typescript'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.5.5
2 info using node@v16.15.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 8ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 8ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\nze\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:\\EFKPDC\home$\nze\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 16ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 16ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
20 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
21 timing npm:load:display Completed in 4ms
22 verbose logfile C:\Users\nze\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-09T11_21_27_816Z-debug-0.log
23 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 16ms
24 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 38ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
28 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
29 timing idealTree Completed in 18ms
30 timing command:install Completed in 43ms
31 verbose stack RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
31 verbose stack     at resolve (node:path:158:10)
31 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:21:10)
31 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
31 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
31 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
31 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
31 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
31 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
31 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
31 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
32 verbose cwd C:\Users\nze\Downloads\dev
33 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
34 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "typescript"
35 verbose node v16.15.0
36 verbose npm  v8.5.5
37 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
38 verbose exit 1
39 timing npm Completed in 410ms
40 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1652095288177
41 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1652095288200
42 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:init 1652095288200
43 verbose code 1
44 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
44 error     C:\Users\nze\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-09T11_21_27_816Z-debug-0.log
```

When im installing without "-g" it runs with no problem, but if im putting the -g in front of it it wont let me install anything.
I almost tried every possible solution on the internet including reinstall but nothing works for me.
any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify this, are you trying to install Typescript globally as stated in message number 34? And did you try to install other pcks too globally? Did you get the same output?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It will give me the same exact error with everything i'm trying to install globally.